# Reducing large polynomial expression to product of simplar polynominals

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, polynomials, factorization

A beginner to Mathematica.

I am trying to express a large symbolic polynomial expression as a product of factors of simpler polynomials:

For example I was able to factor this expression:

```
256. ptz (1. ptx^4 + 1. ptx^2 pty^2 - 2. ptx^3 ptz - 
    2. ptx pty^2 ptz + 1. ptx^2 ptz^2 + 1. pty^2 ptz^2 + 2. ptx^3 px + 
   2. ptx pty^2 px - 2. ptx^2 ptz px - 2. pty^2 ptz px + 
   1. ptx^2 px^2 + 1. pty^2 px^2 - 2. ptx^3 pz - 2. ptx pty^2 pz + 
   2. ptx^2 ptz pz + 2. pty^2 ptz pz - 2. ptx^2 px pz - 
   2. pty^2 px pz + 1. ptx^2 pz^2 + 1. pty^2 pz^2)
```

into

```
256 ptz (ptx^2 + pty^2)(ptx - ptz + px - pz)^2
```

manually. How do I accomplish the same in Mathematica ? I do realize that the factors are not "standard terms". Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Rationalize the coefficients: `Factor[Rationalize[expr]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally good practice to work with exact integers, rationals, roots, etc. when trying to manipulate things in Mathematica.  Your question illustrates why.

```
foo = 256. ptz (1. ptx^4 + 1. ptx^2 pty^2 - 2. ptx^3 ptz - 
     2. ptx pty^2 ptz + 1. ptx^2 ptz^2 + 1. pty^2 ptz^2 + 
     2. ptx^3 px + 2. ptx pty^2 px - 2. ptx^2 ptz px - 
     2. pty^2 ptz px + 1. ptx^2 px^2 + 1. pty^2 px^2 - 2. ptx^3 pz - 
     2. ptx pty^2 pz + 2. ptx^2 ptz pz + 2. pty^2 ptz pz - 
     2. ptx^2 px pz - 2. pty^2 px pz + 1. ptx^2 pz^2 + 
     1. pty^2 pz^2);
bar = Rationalize[foo]

(* 256 ptz (ptx^4 + ptx^2 pty^2 - 2 ptx^3 ptz - 2 ptx pty^2 ptz + 
   ptx^2 ptz^2 + pty^2 ptz^2 + 2 ptx^3 px + 2 ptx pty^2 px - 
   2 ptx^2 ptz px - 2 pty^2 ptz px + ptx^2 px^2 + pty^2 px^2 - 
   2 ptx^3 pz - 2 ptx pty^2 pz + 2 ptx^2 ptz pz + 2 pty^2 ptz pz - 
   2 ptx^2 px pz - 2 pty^2 px pz + ptx^2 pz^2 + pty^2 pz^2) *)

Simplify[bar]

(* 256 (ptx^2 + pty^2) ptz (ptx - ptz + px - pz)^2 *)
```

The `Rationalize` command replaces all expressions involving machine-precision numbers (such as `1.` and `2.`) with exact integers (such as `1` and `2`.)  The `Simplify` function is then able to do much more if it knows that these are exact integer coefficients and not approximate real numbers.  In contrast, simply asking Mathematica to

```
Simplify[foo]
```

does not change the output much (try it!)

For more information on why Mathematica works the way it does, you may find the Wolfram tutorial on [How to Control the Precision and Accuracy of Numerical Results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html) helpful.

Comment: This is one of those questions where the real problem is not what's being directly asked about.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the quick response and also the solution. It does exactly what I was looking for.
I used Simplify[foo] without paying attention to the significance of integers. Thank you again.